# Sorting a structure vector by a value within the struct

Tags: visual-studio, class, c++11, vector, struct

First of all, I would like to thank you for the assistance. I am attempting to sort a vector of structs by a value within the struct, which in this case is an double. The struct looks like this.

```
struct countryInfoStruct
{
    int countryNumber;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    string city;
    string country;
    double distance;
};
```

My vector name is:

```
vector<countryInfoStruct> countries;
```

Which is populated by a .csv file, which works correctly. My problem is sorting. I created a function that is intended to sort the vector; however, something is missing. The error that I am getting is

> CountryData::countryInfoStruct incomplete type is not allowed

I have researched this many times, but have not been able to fix it. The error message is underlining "`countryInfoStruct`". Below is my `sortVector` Function.

```
void CountryData::sortVector()
{
    CountryData m;
    auto sortFunc = [](countryInfoStruct a, countryInfoStruct b) -> bool {
        return a.distance < b.distance;
}
```

Of note: I know that I am missing the iterator below, but this is because I have not been able to get the actual function to work.

```
sort(countries.begin(), countries.end(), sortVector);
```

Comment: The source file where `sortVector` is defined only sees forward declaration for `countryInfoStruct`, but not the full definition.

Comment: Why not simply `std::sort(countries.begin(), countries.end(), [](countryInfoStruct a, countryInfoStruct b) { return a.distance < b.distance; });`? Off Topic: to avoid usefulness copies, I suggest to pass `countryInfoStruct`'s as constant references to the lamda. I mean: `[](countryInfoStruct const & a, countryInfoStruct const & b)`